# UILabel not getting bigger with autolayout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I'm using `autolayout` and my `UILabel` doesn't seem to get bigger when the app is opened on the iphone 6 and 6+. I have the following constraints on the label:

-Vertical spacing to top layout guide

-Vertical spacing to image below label

-Center horizontally in container

I also tried setting an aspect ratio constraint to itself and then a equal widths constraint with the parent view (with multiplier ratio) so that when the width of the parent view expands so would the label but no luck.

Are there settings that I should be implementing to allow this to happen?  I thought labels have intrinsic sizing so they would get larger on their own as the parent view grows.

Comment: In what sense do you want the label to "get bigger"? Do you mean you want bigger _text_? If so, you'll have to make that change in code. Autolayout has nothing whatever to do with that (although a label can _shrink_ its text size as the label gets _smaller_ meaning _narrower_). Otherwise, unless you give the label a background color, how do you _know_ it isn't getting bigger? It could be...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  Yes, I'm referring to the label text. What do you mean I'll have to make the change in code?  Am I setting a size for each phone size?

Comment: Well there you go. You are simply expecting something that is just never going to happen. It's better to learn what _does_ happen so that you _know_ what to expect. Wishing will not make it so.

Answer (score 0):

No, they have intrinsic sizing so they would get larger as their *content* grows (i.e. how much text they contain). *That* is what intrinsic sizing means. It means that the size is *intrinsic*.

Also, resizing a label physically (e.g. making it taller and wider) changes the size of the *label*. This will be evident if your label has a distinct colored background, for instance. It has no direct effect whatever, though, on the size of its text's *font*.